# How do I set .vimrc to always allow cursor moved to the EOL in normal mode?

Tags: vim

I know `$` can move the cursor to the end of line.

But I wonder if there is a way to make the cursor move to the `EOL`(the next place of the end of line).

Because I find when I create a new line using `o`or`O`, the cursor is always at the `EOL` and in all other situations is not. I want it to be accordant in my vim when I typing `$i` (I know there is a better way `A`, but it still bothers me.)

Comment: Doubt1: If I understood correctly what you want to do is the following: "Whenever you press down arrow and go to the next line (which already exists), you want the cursor to go to the ```EOL``` ". Is that correct? \n Doubt 2: You have mentioned "in all other situations it is not". What are those other situations? Could you give and example?

Comment: @vineeshvs 1. i want the cursor just down and all eol of lines can be a cursor moved to. For example: 123，there is 3 chars but i hope when type `$` cursor goes behind '3'(the 4th place)。 2. In a new file:  type`i <esc> o1<esc>` and use 'hjkl' move to anywhere you can.The cursor only stops at 2 places, eol of line1 and first char at line2，but not eol of line2。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VI Editor: Move to EOL instead of last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295887/vi-editor-move-to-eol-instead-of-last-character)

Comment: I guess you got your answer then. Please add your comment also in your question (for more clarity) and post the answer.

Comment: @vineeshvs I don't , I just find the duplicated question. :C

Comment: this doens't answer your question, but it might be a help to you, I was annoyed by this too until I forced myself to use all the different ways of entering insert mode.

Remember that "i" isn't the only option, use "a", "A", "r", "s", "o", "O", and jump to characters using "f", "F", "t", "T". when you learn to use those keys intuitively for the right situation it will make a lot more sense why the cursor is not where you'd "expect" it to be. Vim does not work like most editors and trying to force it to will only bring you heartbreak when you learn bad patterns and must unlearn them later.